# IntelliJ JSX comment in Live Templates does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, jsx, live-templates

I have set up a `Live Template` in `IntelliJ` using [Live template Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html) as reference

```
// Live Template: 
//   $START_COMMENT$ <- commentStart() || blockCommentStart()
//   $END_COMMENT$ <- commentEnd() || blockCommentEnd()
//   $USER$ <- user()
$START_COMMENT$ TODO($USER$): $1$ $END_COMMENT$ 

// jsx file type todo`tab`
OUTPUT with commentStart() + commentEnd(): // TODO(torres): do something later
OUTPUT with blockCommentStart() + blockCommentEnd(): /* TODO(torres): do something later */
EXPECTED: {/** TODO(torres): do something later */}
```

I have tested the `todo` template on HTML, CSS and it adds the appropriate comment tags.

In case it's a bug I did open an issue [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243114)
I expected the `commentStart() || blockCommentStart() + commentEnd() || blockCommentEnd()` to have the same output as <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd>

but I get:

```
JSX file
// `commentStart() + commentEnd()` --> //
// `blockCommentStart() + blockCommentEnd()` --> /* */
// `Ctrl+/` --> {/**/}
```

What Am I missing here?

Comment: there are no workarounds unfortunately, please follow your youtrack ticket for updates